# The Angel Problem - Sticker Devil Variation

Tags: mathematics

So If you are aware of the [angel problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angel_problem), I propose a Variant:
we introduce the Sticker Devil: A normal devil, with the added ability to sacrifice his turn to color any and all White Tiles that are neighboring at least two Black Tiles.
Does the Devil now have a winning strategy?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Please could you provide an explanation of "the angel problem" as this puzzle cannot be answered as written.

Comment: If "neighbouring" includes all the cells a 1-power Angel (aka a chess king) can move into, then almost certainly. But you probably used "neighbouring" to mean "orthogonally adjacent to"?

Comment: No I meant king style. So the former.